# How to find the values in the multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have more than 100 columns inside the dataframe and there are multiple services mentioned in the columns for example

```
Route1 Route2 Route3 .... Route100
```

**Now I have the values like this in the columns**

```
Route1     Route2    Route3    ....          Route100
   ax        bc        dd      ....             xe
   bc        dd        xe      ....             ax
   dd        ax        da      ....             ki
```

**I want to select all the rows having values from ax to dd and dd to ax**

this is some how i have tried but this is not working because i have multiple columns

```
 df.ne('ax').dot(df.columns)
```

**The expected outcome should be**

```
Route1    Route2     Route3    ....          Route100
   ax       -          dd      ....             -
    -       dd         -      ....              ax
   dd       ax         -      ....              -
```

Comment: I didn't understand, do you want to change the ax values to dd and dd values to ax ?

Comment: @OussamaJabri I just want to select these rows

Comment: What is your expected outcome from the sample data?

Comment: @QuangHoang  I have mentioned the expected outcome please look

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you are looking for `isin` and boolean mask:

```
mask = df.isin(['ax','dd'])
df[mask]
```

Output:

```
  Route1 Route2 Route3  ... Route100
0     ax    NaN     dd  ...      NaN
1    NaN     dd    NaN  ...       ax
2     dd     ax    NaN  ...      NaN
```

Comment: Can we delete the rows which contain ALL NAN VALUES

Comment: not working.. I have 1200 rows in which showing NAN

Comment: `df.dropna(axis=1, how='all', inplace=True)`

Comment: still showing NAN in all rows After deleting the NAN rows I can filter that out

Comment: My mistake, try: `df.dropna(how='all', inplace=True)`.

Comment: all rows either containing true or false... now the results are missing

Answer (score -1):

Make that into a dictionary and then you can use loop fucntion. Something like this :

```
For values in Route 
(
df.ne('ax').dot(df.columns)
)
```